# Eager loadings for single object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a controller that find 1 record (its uniq)

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @collection = Collection.find_by_active(true)
  end
end
```

This '@collection' have many :items, which has many :photos

So, in view it look like this:

```
- @collection.items.each do |item|
    = image_tag item.find_active_photo.image_url(:small)
```

And it will reproduce bunch of SQL queries, for example if item has 4 photos, it will be 6 queries:

```
Collection Load 
CollectionItem Load 
Photo Load (4 times)
```

How I can reduce count of this N+1 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use eager loading

```
@collection = Collection.find_by_active(true, {:include =>{:items => :photos})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an "includes" method of ActiveRecord. It allows to preload records.

`Collection.find_by_active(true).includes(:items)`

Not sure, if you can do something like `includes(items: :photo)`, but give it a try.

Comment: It's not work for single object. only for collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4

```
@collection = Collection.includes(items: :photos).find_by_active(true)
```